# How to display text and a button inlined in react native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I want to get the following result in `react-native`:

[image]

I use styled-components and I am using `styled.Text` for the grey text, and  `styled.TouchableOpacity` for the red text but I can't get them inlined after playing with all the styling.

How can I achieve the desired result?

**Edit**, after reading the answer here, this is the result I am currently having:

[image]

This is how my source code like:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <MoreInformationContainer>
      <Typo.Caption color={ColorsEnum.GREY_DARK}>
        {_(t`Pour plus d'informations, nous t'invitons à consulter notre`)}
        <AppButton
          title={_(t`Politique des cookies`)}
          // onPress={dismissModal}
          icon={ExternalLinkSite}
          textSize={12}
          disabled
          inline
        />
      </Typo.Caption>
    </MoreInformationContainer>
  )
}
const MoreInformationContainer = styled.View({
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  position: 'relative',
})
```

And this is my `AppButton` component:

https://gist.github.com/83f5b6b91f015a75340d0664f79529fb

As you can see, I use an `inline` props to apply the inline style. I've just tried to position the bottom of the clickable link, and I couldn't found a css that does that, any clue ?

Comment: you should be good by using `display: inline;`

Comment: That doesn't exist in react native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> flexDirection: 'row'

in the parent view to display inline

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <Styled.Text />
  <Styled.TouchableOpacity />
</View>

<AppButton
  style={{bottom: -5}}
  title={_(t`Politique des cookies`)}
  // onPress={dismissModal}
  icon={ExternalLinkSite}
  textSize={12}
  disabled
  inline
/>;
```

Comment: Hi and thankx, how do you tel the touchable opacity to move a bit it's bottom position? *(see updated question)*

Comment: Add bottom to some negative number for AppButton style

Answer (score 1):

working example in expo

```
  <View style = {{flexDirection:'row',flexWrap:'wrap'}}><Text style >This some text you want to render inline things to do wwhat we want<TouchableOpacity><Text>Some other text clicable</Text></TouchableOpacity> </Text></View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/65Rjb6L79

Comment: Hi and thanks, I took your example and tried to build my own, I updated the question, I keep having issue with the positioning of the touchable opacity.

Comment: just add marginTop: to the item  or paddingTop

Comment: I tried both, both don't change the positioning, I've also tried many flex css such as `alignSelf`, `alignContent`, `justifyContent`, etc... nothing helped